# Vue3 and foundation : how to make vertical tabs from an array of object?

Tags: vuejs3, foundation

I am starting with Foundation and rather new to vuejs also.
I try to make a tabbed view based on an array of objects namely events (nothing to do with event in the computer science acception but event in common life)

I managed to have the ul on the left and the panel on the right but in the panel all the tab contents are displayed.
I think it is due to the fact that I don't know how to create the href of the a link properly.

Here is my code

```
<div class="grid-container fluid">
    <div class="grid-x">
        <div class="cell medium-3">
            <ul class="vertical tabs" data-tabs id="example-tabs">
                <li v-for="(event, index) in props.events" key="index" class="tabs-title " :class="index==0? 'is-active': ''"><a
                        href="`#panel_${index}`" aria-selected="true">{{ event.label }}</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="cell medium-9">
            <div class="tabs-content vertical" data-tabs-content="example-tabs">
                <div v-for="(event, index) in props.events" key="index" class="tabs-panel" :class="index==0? 'is-active': ''"
                    id="`panel_${index}`">

                    <p>Check me out! I'm a super cool Tab panel with text content!</p>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Hereafter a picture of what is displayed in the browser

[image]
With this code, when inspecting the document in the browser, all the href are the same exactly as writen in the code.
In fact I don't know how to convert e.g for index=4  index into href="#panel_4" .
Thank in advance for help

Comment: I forgot to bind the href so I changed it to :href="`#panel_${index}` and the same for the tabs. Now I have good indexes and only one displayed but all the links on the left are highlighted as if selected and I cannot change the displayed event. Inspecting in the browser only the index 0 has active class.